# "Что-то(,) вроде..."

Tags: пунктуация

Вечно у меня обнаруживается куча лишних запятых. Теперь вот засомневался: нужна ли запятая в обороте "Что-то, вроде (чего-то)"? Сначала поставил, потом убрал. Правильно?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Птица вроде воробья. "Жизнь, или что-то вроде того".

Запятая перед "вроде" не ставится, так как ВРОДЕ - это предлог со значением сходства или соответствия, его близким синонимом является предлог НАПОДОБИЕ: "Признаюсь, сколько я ни старался различить вдалеке что-нибудь наподобие лодки, но безуспешно".